# URI Start of MAUI Android App creates a new instance

Tags: android, maui

I am able to start my MAUI Android App using URI,but when I have an instance of the app that is minimized and click on URI appears that a new instance of the app is being created and exception is thrown.

If my app is already running, I want to use that instance.

I have this in my manifest file :

```html
    <activity android:exported="false" android:allowBackup="true"  android:supportsRtl="true"     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="FF.Client.MAUI.MainActivity" android:debuggable="true" android:extractNativeLibs="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="flexyfit.bg"
                android:pathPrefix="/video" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is my MainActivity :

```html
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
                  DataScheme = "https",
                  DataHost = "test.com",
                  DataPathPrefix = "/hello",
                  AutoVerify = true,
                  Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.ActionView })]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    public static MainActivity Instance { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<object> PrivateNotificationSent = delegate { };
    public MainActivity()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
        Intent intent = this.Intent;
        this.OnNewIntent(intent);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);

        var data = intent.DataString;

        if (intent.Action != Intent.ActionView) return;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data)) return;
        
        if (data.Contains("/hello"))
        {
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SomePage))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We are not wizards bro, we might need to see your code to tell you what the issue is....

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help you if there is any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If my app is already running, I want to use that instance.

You can add the `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` into the manifest file, such as:

```
<activity android:exported="false" android:allowBackup="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
```

The default value of the `android:launchMode` is standard. If you don’t set any launch mode to your activity, it will use the standard mode by default. It creates a new instance of activity every time even if activity instance is already present.

For more information, you can check [the official document about the `android:launchMode`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element).